# How to convert NUMBER DataType to DATE DataType in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Hi i have csv file data e.g:- **(ActiveDate= 20180105)** so I want to save this column to my database. In my database column datatype is **datetime** .

And while using data conversion as **DT_Date** i am getting this error:-

> The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value
>   could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.

So how can i import this ActiveDate data from my excel to my database as **datetime** ?

Can you help me out..?

Comment: Did you try what was suggested by @Justin? What is the current error that you are getting?

Comment: Yes i am getting THIS ERROR:-  `[Derived Column [36]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.  [Derived Column [48]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[DERIVED_ADMIT_DATE]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

Comment: Before doing `CAST` in `Derived Column` have you converted your input `Number` to `String` using `Data Conversion` ?

Comment: @Abhishek :- Yes i have done that

Comment: There must be something wrong in your implementation, you might had missed something - cause the method described works very much fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must first convert Your column `YYYYMMDD` To String in `Data Conversion` element like this:

```
  Input Column   Output Column   Data Type                      Length 
  IntDate       StringDate      Unicode string [DT_WSTR]        50
```

and then you can use this formula in `Derived Column` element to convert new string column to real date:

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(StringDate,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(StringDate,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(StringDate,7,2))
```

For data with null in date column use this formula, this formula gonna change null in current date:

```
isnull(StringDate)? GETDATE() : (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(StringDate,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(StringDate,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(StringDate,7,2))
```

Results:

```
IntDate     StringDate  DateDate
20170809    20170809    2017-08-09 00:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: Hi Justin.. I am new to SSIS. Can you please tell me after using data conversion to Unicode String.. How to use formula in derived column in ssis.??

Comment: How can i achieve  only date (e.g:- 2017/08/09) this format in derived column.?? and i don't need time

Comment: 1. For Derived column Example search in Google you just need to paste code and change StringDate to your column. 2. If you writing to database it doesnt matter what type of date you inserting.

Comment: Hey i have done that derived column.. but still getting this error:-    `[Derived Column [48]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[DERIVED_ADMIT_DATE]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

Comment: :-   This error also  `[Derived Column [36]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
`

Comment: One more thing some of the value in my source file having null value. Does it cause any problem..?

Comment: @jack   any solution do you have..?

Comment: I edited my answer, use second formula if you got null in date column. This formula gonna change null in current date